# Binary Relation and Quotient Set

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $A=\{1,3\}$. In $\mathcal P(X)$ the following binary relation is defined: $$ B \sim C \Leftrightarrow B\cap \bar{A} = C\cap \bar{A}. $$

Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation and calculate the quotient set $\mathcal P(X)/\sim$.

Comment: What is $\bar{A}$?

Comment: A complement of a set A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, about $\sim$ being an equivalence relation. Consider the map $f : \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(X \cap \bar{A}) = \mathcal{P}(X \setminus A)$ that maps $B \mapsto B \cap \bar{A}$. Then $B \sim C$ if and only if $f(B) = f(C)$. This implies immediately that this is an equivalence relation, as $B \sim C$ means *$B$ and $C$ have the **same** image under $f$*.

Now $f$ is easily verified to be onto. By what is sometimes called the first isomorphism theorem for sets, there is a natural bijection between $\mathcal{P}(X) / \sim$ and $\mathcal{P}(X \cap \bar{A})$, that is, the elements of $\mathcal{P}(X) / \sim$ are the preimages $f^{-1}(U)$ of the elements of $U \in \mathcal{P}(X \cap \bar{A})$. And one verifies that $f^{-1}(U) = \{ U \cup V : V \in \mathcal{P}(A)  \}$.

Answer (score 0):

First want to show that it is reflexive, that is, $B\sim B$. It is clear that $$B\cap \bar{A}=B\cap\bar{A} $$ which imples that $B\sim B$.

Now to show that it is symmetric, that is, if $ B\sim C $ then we must have $C\sim B$: if $B\sim C$ then we have $$B\cap \bar{A}=C\cap\bar{A}$$ which is the same as $$C\cap \bar{A}=B\cap \bar{C}.$$ But this is exactly  $C\sim B$ as required.

Finally want to show that it is transitive, that is, if $B\sim C$ and $ C \sim D$ then we have $B\sim D$: if $B\sim C$ then $$B\cap \bar{A}=C\cap\bar{A}$$ and if $ C\sim D$ then we have $$C\cap \bar{A}=D\cap\bar{A}.$$ But then we have $$B\cap \bar{A}=D\cap\bar{A}$$ which implies that $B\sim D$. Thus, it is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Thank you :) but and calculate the quotient set P(X)/R?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there's no explicit answer given to the question what the equivalence classes look like and it seems worth it to give this description, since it's not that hard and in my opinion forms the most interesting part of this question.

Two subsets of $X$ are equivalent under $\sim$, if they have the same intersection with the complement of $A$. That means they are equivalent if they contain exactly the same elements of $\{2,4,5\}$. The different equivalence classes therefore correspond one-to-one with $\mathcal{P}(\{2,4,5\})$.

To see this, we first remark that if $B,C \in\mathcal{P}(\{2,4,5\})$ are different, it follows that $B\cap \bar{A} = B \neq C = C\cap \bar{A}$ and so they have to be in different equivalence classes.

Next we take an arbitrary $B\in\mathcal{P}(\{2,4,5\})$. What does its equivalence class look like? The intersection with the complement of $A$ doesn't change if we add some $1$ or $3$ to it - it disappears when intersecting anyway. We thus see that $[B]_\sim=\{B,B\cup\{1\},B\cup\{3\},B\cup\{1,3\}\}$.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote above; "there is a natural bijection between $\mathcal{P}(X) / \sim$ and $\mathcal{P}(X \cap \bar{A})$, that is, the elements of $\mathcal{P}(X) / \sim$ are the preimages $f^{-1}(U)$ of the elements of $U \in \mathcal{P}(X \cap \bar{A})$. And one verifies that $f^{-1}(U) = \{ U \cup V : V \in \mathcal{P}(A)  \}$." 

Here of course $X \setminus A = \{ 2, 4, 5 \}$, and  $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{ \emptyset, \{ 1 \}, \{ 3 \} \{ 1, 3 \}\}$.